# WSO2 EI, loading validation schemas from property

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have one sequence that will load from registry specific JSON validation schema from registry, depending on value of request body:

```
<switch description="" source="get-property('uri.var.service')">
    <case regex="1">
        <property expression="base64Decode(get-property('registry', 'conf:/schemas/1'))" name="schema" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    </case>
    <case regex="2">
        <property expression="base64Decode(get-property('registry', 'conf:/schemas/2'))" name="schema" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    </case>
</switch>
```

Then I try to validate from it:

```
<validate cache-schema="true" source="json-eval($)">
    <schema key="{get-property('schema')}"/>
</validate>
```

However, this throws me this error:

```
 ValidateMediator Can not find JSON Schema {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "uin": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "uin"
  ]
}
```

Why I can't load proper schema from property? Also, there is no examples regarding dynamic keys for JSON validation in WSO2 EI's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the validate mediator implementation [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/builtin/ValidateMediator.java), only the schema key can be loaded from the registry and not the entire schema. In your case, the entire schema is loaded in place of the schema key. As a solution, you can define the schema property as just a string value.

```
<property name="schema" scope="default" type="STRING" value="conf:/schema.json"/>
```